# Adding a token to a http for AWS api gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jwt, token, aws-api-gateway

I'm using the code below to create a http request to my amazon AWS api gateway with an object (mp3Base64) as its content. However, it needs to have the authorization token attached. Can anyone explain how this is done and show an example? Any help is gratefully received. Thanks.

```
public String executePost(String targetURL, Mp3Base64 mp3Base64) throws IOException {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String mp3Base64Json = mapper.writeValueAsString(mp3Base64);
URL obj = new URL(targetURL);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
Integer.toString(mp3Base64Json.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

//Send request
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes("base64=" + mp3Base64Json);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

//Get Response
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + targetURL);
System.out.println("Post parameters : base64 =" + mp3Base64Json);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
     response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: The token is just a header on the request... Guessing it's just a jwt?

Comment: connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer tokenGoesHere");